# Spark: How to overwrite a file on S3 folder and not complete folder

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-2.0

Using Spark I am trying to push some data(in csv, parquet format) to S3 bucket.

```
df.write.mode("OVERWRITE").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(nullValue=options['nullValue'], header=options['header'], delimiter=options['delimiter'], quote=options['quote'], escape=options['escape']).save(destination_path)
```

In above code piece, destination_path variable holds the S3 bucket location where data needs to be exported.

Eg. `destination_path = "s3://some-test-bucket/manish/"`

In the folder `manish` of `some-test-bucket` if I have several files and sub-folders. Above command will delete all of them and spark will write new output files. But I want to overwrite just one file with this new file.

Even if I am able to overwrite just contents of this folder, but sub-folder remain intact even that would solve the problem to certain extent.

How can this be achieved?

I tried to use mode as append instead of overwrite.

Here in this case subfolder name remains intact but again all the contents of `manish` folder and its sub-folder are overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Set the Spark configuration parameter `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode` to `dynamic` instead of static. This will only overwrite the necessary partitions and not all of them.
PySpark example:

```
conf=SparkConf().setAppName("test).set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic").setMaster("yarn")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Answer (score 1):

The file's can be deleted first and then use append mode to insert the data instead of overwriting to retain the sub folder's. Below is an example from Pyspark.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm", "{}*.csv.deflate".format(destination_path)])

df.write.mode("append").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(nullValue=options['nullValue'], header=options['header'], delimiter=options['delimiter'], quote=options['quote'], escape=options['escape']).save(destination_path)
```